# MYSQL PHP form submit issue

Tags: php, mysql, forms, wordpress

I have a form with the action of this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_10_options (option_name, option_value) VALUES ($key, $val) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option_value = $val;");
    }
```

and the actual code in the form is this:

```
$args = array(
                'type'                     => 'post',
                'hide_empty'               => 0, //<--IMPORTANT!!
                'hierarchical'             => 1,
                'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
                'pad_counts'               => false );
                $categories = get_categories($args);
                foreach($categories as $category) { 
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo "<td>$category->name</td>";
                        $sql = "SELECT option_value FROM wp_10_options WHERE option_name='$category->slug'";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                          {
                         echo "<td><input type='text' name='$category->slug' value='".$row['option_value']."' /></td>";
                          }

                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
```

Yet it adds nothing to the table? Can someone see why? I have checked and the post data is being sent? And it connects to the DB fine?

Before you all ask, yes I realize the security threats and etc...

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put $key and $val and $val in quotation marks in the SQL for posting to the database.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) 
    { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_10_options (option_name, option_value) VALUES ('$key', '$val') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option_value = '$val';"); 
    }
```

You say you know about security threats: see the comment under your question about using PDO/Prepared statements and this problem would magically disappear and make it more secure (and actually be faster for multiple inserts like this!)

Comment: Nope, quotation marks do nothing, and I know its not them. I am aware of PDO, and have spent ages trying to convince the client, but in the end gave up.

Comment: You're the coder, you're the one that has to deal with the problem when the site goes wrong - the client doesn't really need to know if you're using PDO or the old functions :) . Anyhow, for the question, echo out the SQL at the same time. If no "echo" then it's something outside the code you've given us. If you do get an echo, run through phpMyAdmin to see what happens. Note that some SQL servers won;t let you add semi-colon to the end of a query (for security). Try dropping that as well.